# databinding to a datarow

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm using DataBindings to an untyped DataTable like the following

```
textbox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _dataTable, columnName );
```

Now the databinding works fine, however, I was checking the state of the row (after changing a value, of course) and it shows Unchanged. Just wondering shouldn't that be Modified?

```
_dataTable.Rows[0]
{System.Data.DataRow}
    HasErrors: false
    ItemArray: {object[11]}
    RowError: ""
    RowState: Unchanged
    Table: {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `_dataTable.BeginEdit()` and `_dataTable.EndEdit()` to changed the row state to Modified.

Answer (score 1):

call _dataTable.**AcceptChanges()** to commit your changes to row.